# Pagination not working in custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, pagination

I am new in wordpress, I want show pagination in custom post type query but pagination not show in frontend, can any one see my code where i am doing wrong:

```
  <?php 
// the query

$paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;

$wpb_all_query = new WP_Query(array('post_type'=>'german_post', 'post_status'=>'publish', 'posts_per_page'=>12,'order' => 'DESC','paged' => $paged,'orderby' => 'date'));

 ?>
    <?php if ( $wpb_all_query->have_posts() ) : ?>
    <div class="row" id="post_content">
      <?php while ( $wpb_all_query->have_posts() ) : $wpb_all_query->the_post(); ?>
      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" id="post_container">
        <div class="post-box" > 
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="clickable_box"></a>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">
          <div class="post-img" style="background-image:url(<?php the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>)">
            <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) : ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
          </div>
          </a>
          <div class="post-small-details"> <span class="interests">
            <ul class="list-inline">
              <li><?php echo get_the_term_list(get_the_ID(), 'geram_category'); ?></li>
            </ul>
            </span> <span class="divider">&nbsp;/</span>
            <div class="post-created"><?php echo get_the_date('d.m.Y',$post->ID);?></div>
            <div class="clear-both"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="post-title-container">
            <div class="post-title">
              <h2>
                <?php  $content = get_the_title();
                                   $content = strip_tags($content);
                                          echo substr($content, 0, 65); ?>
              </h2>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="post-details">
            <?php the_excerpt();?>
          </div>
          <div class="like_box gr_like_box">

                                <ul>

                                    <li class="share_post">
                                        <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri (); ?>/images/share.svg" width="34px">
                                        <div class="post_share">
                                            <a href="https://plus.google.com/share?url=<?php the_permalink(); ?>" onclick="javascript:window.open(this.href,
  '', 'menubar=no,toolbar=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,height=600,width=600');return false;">
                                            <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri (); ?>/images/article_share_img/gplus.svg" width="25px">
                                        </a>
                                       <a href="http://twitter.com/home/?status=<?php the_title(); ?> - <?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="Tweet this!">
                                            <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri (); ?>/images/article_share_img/twitter.svg" width="25px">
                                        </a>
                                        <a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=<?php the_permalink();?>&amp;t=<?php the_title(); ?>" title="Share on Facebook." target="_blank">
                                            <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri (); ?>/images/article_share_img/facebook.svg" width="25px">
                                        </a>
                                        <a href="http://www.reddit.com/submit?url=<?php the_permalink(); ?>&amp;title=<?php the_title(); ?>" title="Vote on Reddit">

                                            <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri (); ?>/images/article_share_img/reddit.svg" width="25px">
                                        </a>
                                        <a href="http://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=<?php the_title(); ?> - <?php the_permalink(); ?>&media=<?php $url = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID) ); echo $url; ?>">
                                            <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri (); ?>/images/article_share_img/pinterest.svg" width="25px">
                                        </a>
                                        <a href="mailto:?subject=<?php the_title(); ?>&amp;body=<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="Contact us">
                                            <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri (); ?>/images/article_share_img/email.svg" width="25px">
                                        </a>
                                        </div>

                                    </li>

                                    <li><?php  echo CS_Likes::show_buttons_like(); ?></li>

                                </ul>
                            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <?php endwhile; ?>
      <!-- end of the loop -->

      <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
    </div>
    <div class="loader-box">
      <?php the_posts_pagination(); ?>
    </div>
    <?php else : ?>
    <p>
      <?php _e( 'Leider gibt es keinen Treffer, der mit dem Suchbegriff übereinstimmt. Ändern Sie das Suchwort und versuchen Sie es bitte erneut.' ); ?>
    </p>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Why are you using a custom query?

Comment: Hey @JacobPeattie I am new in wordpress, I just copy paste it, Can you tell what should i do ?

Comment: have you tried searching here? this question has been asked many times.

Answer (score 0):

As far  I read in your comment, it isn't requires for you to handle it with a custom query. So if you register your custom post type with `'has_archive' => true`, then you can just reach the archive of the custom post type at `http://www.yourwebsite.com/your-cpt-slug/`.

**Important:** Remember to flush the rewrite rules after you change somethign related to your permalinks. You can do it just visiting *Settings > Permalinks*

See how [register_post_type](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type) works for any doubt, it's always lighting.